# Grouping Approach in Kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

we have one use case to group multiple data messages and then process them

**Sample Data Message**

```
{
    "meta": {
        "id": "66b3cd0e-6a15-4730-a5c8-71ca6dd601a5",
        "userId": "47922F57-2C49-4B0B-A34B-08C9E6A15CC",
    },
    "data": [
        {
            "Email": "user1@email.com",
            "FirstName": "User 1",
            "LastName": "Last 1",
        }, 
        {
            "Email": "user2@email.com",
            "FirstName": "User 2",
            "LastName": "Last 2",
        }, 
    ]
}
```

We are continuously getting similar messages with different  Identifier as (meta.id+meta.userId) and with multiple records in data array

What we want to do is group messages based on (meta.id+meta.userId) and then process them

- either periodically with an interval of 5 min.
- or if for an identifier we got x Data-records.

This question might be vague, we want to know how can we achieve this grouping using Kafka if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use kafka streams to do that so basically your topology will looks something like:

```
val kStream = streamsBuilder.stream(YOUR_TOPIC, YOUR_SERDES)
kStream.groupBy(k ,v ->v.meta)
       .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofMinutes(5)))
```

However you should know that using groupBy will cause data re-partitioning.
You can found more details [here](https://kafka.apache.org/20/documentation/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html)